# Select multiple values from a single field mysql php my admin

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Here is the thing.
I am trying to create an oop php login form.There are 2 tables, users and applications where applications have 2 fields -> title [50 chars]
-> active [boolean] in which I have set the title as primary key. By the other hand The users table construction is : id->primary key,name [50 chars],password [50 chars] and in the end the foreign key from applications ,title.

Also when I am tryinf for an example to select the user with 2 titls ,eg , a user with 2 applications and since I insert the data to the database I canot select it. When the other users with one title->application are displayed normally.
SO my question is why I cannot display one user with 2 values as a title instead of user with one value.

here is my code :

```
1)Part with the necessary part of selection.

<?php
define('DB_SERVER','localhost');
define('DB_USER','super_user');
define('DB_PASS' ,'fotis281986#');
define('DB_NAME', 'login_oop');

class DB_con
{


    function __construct()
    {
        $conn = mysql_connect(DB_SERVER,DB_USER,DB_PASS) or die('localhost connection problem'.mysql_error());
        mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $conn);
    }

    public function select()
    {
        $res = mysql_query("SELECT u.* , a.* FROM users u,applications a WHERE u.title = a.title");
        //$length = mysql_field_len($res, $title);
//echo $length;
        if($res === FALSE) { 
    die(mysql_error()); // TODO: better error handling
} else {return $res;}

    }

2)Part with important parts of index.php

    <?php 
    include_once 'mysql.php';
    $con = new DB_con();
    $res=$con->select();
    $res2= $con->select_app();
    ?>

    <?php
        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res))
        {
                ?>
                <tr>
                <td><?php echo $row['id']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['name']; ?></td>
             <td><?php echo($row['title']); ?> </td>



                <td align="center"><a href="javascript:edit_id(<?php echo $row[0]; ?>)"><img src="b_edit.png" alt="EDIT" /></a></td>
                <td align="center"><a href="javascript:del_id(<?php echo $row[0]; ?>)"><img src="b_drop.png" alt="DELETE" /></a></td>
                </tr>


                <?php
        }
      ?><td align="center"><a href="javascript:create_id(<?php echo $row[0]; ?>)"><img src="b_create.png" alt="create" /></a></td> 
        </table>
```

| id | name    | password  | title
:----|--------:|   ------: |:------:
| 1  |  admin  | 12345     |app1,app2

Comment: Stop. Before you look for a solution, go some steps back and improve your programming skills. First of all stop using `mysql_*` - deprecated and removed in PHP7. Use mysqli or PDO instead, they're supported AND they have an OOP interface, so it will be much better to use them. Also visit http://bobby-tables.com to learn about SQL injection and how to prevent them. Also, don't store passwords as plaintext. Please encrypt it before saving in your database. Be aware that a login system is complex and not that easy as many think. Maybe look for free solutions and build your system around them.

Comment: Hello and thank you for your response! I just setted the password as plain text for debuging reasons only. I will fix it later. For now I just want to display 2 values of a single field.Thank you again!

Comment: Ever thought about e 3rd table? First user table `ID, username, password` second one your app tables `ID, title, active` and a 3rd table like connections between these two... `UserID, appID / or title` (I recommend you to set the primary key to a ID, then you can use auto increment.) So you can do as many entrys as you want in the "connection" table.. for example `UserName1, App1` `UserName1, App2` and so on.